# Spring Controller return static HTML site from any directory

Tags: spring

I would like to return in my `@Controller` static HTML website that was generated by other process. Let's say that generated `.html` files are in `/tmp/generated`. I'm trying to read file and pass its content to ResponseEntity:

```
@GetMapping(value = "test")
ResponseEntity<String> test(@RequestParam("filename") String filename) throws IOException {
    String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("/tmp/generated/" + filename)), "UTF-8");

    final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML);
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(content, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

But when I open url in browser I get badly encoded html content (stating and ending with '"'):

```
"\u003chtml\u003e\n\u003chead\u003e\n \u003cmeta charset\u003d\"utf-8\" /\u003e\n \u003cmeta http-equiv\u003d\"X-UA-Compatible\" content\u003d\"IE\u003dedge\" /\u003e\n \u003cmeta name\u003d\"viewport\" content\u003d\"width\u003ddevice-width, initial-scale\u003d1\" /\u003e [.....]
```

If I add `produces = MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE` to my `@GetMapping` annotation then I get `406 Not Acceptable` error response (but no exception in my spring app)...

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you are facing problems when using produces in your mapping.

I gave a quick try and it worked for me.

```
@GetMapping(value = "test", produces=MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<String> test(@RequestParam("filename") String filename) throws IOException {
    String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("/tmp/generated/" + filename)), "UTF-8");
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(content, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Tested in Chrome browser:

[image]

File
[image]

NOTE: I tested this controller using SpringBoot v2.0.5.RELEASE

Cheers!

Comment: thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I'm using old Spring Boot 1.5.2.RELEASE - project is over 2 years old. I'm not sure if I will be able to change it to >=2

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully build application with Spring Boot 1.5.2.RELEASE and it will return static HTML site from any directory

you can checkout [here](https://github.com/GovindParashar136/spring-boot-web-jsp.git)